Updating a Select Into table
I have made a table "winner" from table "DIBBS.nsn" using
SELECT *
INTO "winner"
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         nsn_part_number, 
         reason, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY nsn_part_number ORDER BY date_accessed DESC) rn
     FROM 
         DIBBS_nsn
     WHERE
         order_status = 'WON') a
WHERE rn = 1

This takes all nsn_part_numbers and reason for any status that is "WON" Also with duplicates, it takes the latest dated part number and reason.
I am trying to figure out how to keep this table updated with the DIBBS_nsn. The DIBBS_nsn will have new rows added everyday.
What I have tried:
MERGE INTO winner AS target
USING dibbs_nsn AS source ON (target.nsn_part_number = source.nsn_part_number)
                          AND (source.order_status = 'WON')

WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (nsn_part_number, reason)
         VALUES (source.nsn_part_number, source.reason)

This insert doesn't filter out any of the duplicates, which makes sense but don't really know how to put that in.
Currently my work around for this is that I delete the table and re make the table which in turns updates "winner" using the updates DIBBS_nsn.
I believe there's a query to update, maybe upsert? I looked into it but am a little confused because of the way my select into only takes the most recent dated part number.
What I need: a query that I can run, use in task manager daily to update the "winner" table after new rows have been added to DIBBS_nsn.

Please show: your Postgres version; exact CREATE TABLE statement for (relevant part of) table dibbs_nsn; (possibly) relevant indexes on the table; how many rows total, how many distinct nsn_part_number, how many with order_status = 'WON' per  nsn_part_number? how many new rows per update? what percentage of rows is updated in winner each time?

The use of SELECT INTO in SQL is discouraged. Use CREATE TABLE AS instead.

Creating temporary tables in SQL

CREATE TABLE winner AS  -- !
SELECT DISTINCT ON (nsn_part_number)  -- !
       nsn_part_number, reason
FROM   dibbs_nsn
WHERE  order_status = 'WON'
ORDER  BY nsn_part_number, date_accessed DESC;  -- !

See:

Select first row in each GROUP BY group?

Didn't include the redundant rn in the table.
Add a PK after creating the table. Every table should have one, and we need it for the next step:
ALTER TABLE winner ADD PRIMARY KEY (nsn_part_number);  -- !

Your daily (?) update can then work as UPSERT:
INSERT INTO winner (nsn_part_number, reason)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (nsn_part_number)
       nsn_part_number, reason
FROM   dibbs_nsn
WHERE  order_status = 'WON'
ORDER  BY nsn_part_number, date_accessed DESC
ON     CONFLICT (nsn_part_number) DO UPDATE  -- !
SET    reason = excluded.reason;  -- !

This works well for few qualifying rows per nsn_part_number. For more than a few, other query techniques are (much) faster. Depends on undisclosed information.
See:

How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?
Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user

